# For dark, mysterious and unspecified reasons, "We cannot accept this question"

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, low-quality-posts

The `Sorry, we cannot accept this question` message **needs** to link to [an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question).

Otherwise, it becomes useless; we get even-worse questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6061529/revisions#spacer-51117d93-e69f-47a5-a5da-68a7ccdc632b), or Meta questions like [th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/i-am-not-able-to-post-in-stackoverflow-com)[e](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91740/what-does-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-mean)[se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91228/sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-why).

> [<sup>why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?
>
>   ​
>
>   '.$i.''; } ?>
>
>   ​
>
>   i just don't know how to make it work; i want to get the output like this:
>   total = a1,f1,t1;a2,f2,t2;a3,f3,t3;... as long as it user inputs value.
>
>   ​
>
>   thank you.</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6061529/revisions#spacer-51117d93-e69f-47a5-a5da-68a7ccdc632b)

Comment: Doesn't it already link?  I seem to recall this feature requested some time ago, and it being completed...

Comment: @Adam: If it does, it's not helping.  **EDIT**: I just tried it; there is no link.  It just says `Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Sorry, we can't accept this question`

Comment: @SLaks I think the problem is that people aren't reading.  they don't read the faq, the "how to ask questions properly" page you have to click through in order to ask a question, and the actual error you receive when you post too many bad questions.  I don't think there's a way we can change that error message to make them read it better...

Comment: They should see a 5em type message/link consisting only of: **FAQ you!**

Comment: @Adam: That might be true.  However, it really isn't clear that the message is related to what they just read.

Comment: The trouble with the message is that it implies a problem on *our* end. Needs to imply *they* have a problem, something like, "Your question failed to pass our quality filter" or maybe just "Your question sucks."

Comment: How about we automatically redirect them to experts exchange.

Comment: @Adam You're thinking of the "We're no longer accepting questions/answers from this account" message, which *does* link. The plain "We cannot accept this question" does not have a link.

Comment: Haha.  I would have expected seeing that sort of question here on meta, rather than on SO.

Comment: @SLaks: I am especially amused by the second revision in the first question you linked, which fixes the formatting on the code, but leaves the "why cannot accept this question?why cannot accept this question?" text. :)

Comment: **Solution:** If a user attempts to ask why their question can't be accepted, just show a message that says: `“We cannot accept this question”.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make the "Sorry, we can't accept this question" message more helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful)

Comment: i've just been bitten by this; English is my mother tongue; i have to wonder how much the challenge is for ESL persons. one answer below suggests it's something to do with secret spam filters. to me, it's like trying to order food at a restaurant where no patron is allowed to view the menu. B-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See:

[Make the "Sorry, we can't accept this question" message more helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987)

Changed the message to:

> > **Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:**
> >     It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: I still think there ought to be more detail.  How about `Please read this for more detail`?

Comment: @SLaks - Did you read the other answer linked here?  We are not explicit about what reasoning goes into the filter to prevent gaming it.

Comment: @Nick: I don't mean to provide more detail about the filter.  I mean to provide more detail about what a high-quality question looks like.

Comment: After seeing this message, people should have an obvious place to turn to figure out what the problem is and how to improve their questions.  Even a link to how-to-ask would help, IMHO.

Comment: @SLaks, they already clicked through /how-to-ask and totally ignored it ... something tells me they will ignore it second time around

Answer (score 7):

The reason could be placed in a popup, the user would then scroll to the bottom of the popup to check a box ("I understand my post needs improvement.") and fill out a captcha. Grey out the submit until they make any/some change.

Cumbersome but it would weed out those just not willing to make something work.

Answer (score 6):

Hm, I just posted a comment to someone who suggested this in an answer to [the FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91072/131713), not realizing that this question was here. Here's a copy:

> You are not alone in thinking this; see @trampster's comment on [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question/91078#91078) to this question and its 23 upvotes. But remember that these guidelines — which I also subscribe to — are ultimately designed to make life easier and/or better for users. In this case, that's not the goal. Jeff stated in a reply to trampster that when users reach the point of seeing non-descriptive error messages, he's actively trying to drive them away from the SE network. With that goal in mind, it strangely makes sense to break with usual design best practices.

I will add that I don't agree with Jeff's goal. But it is clear that the current system, with its unclear error messages, is well-designed to support the goal.

My point with all of this is that simply asking for a better message is doomed to be declined. If you want the message to change, you'll have to convince Jeff that his goal is wrong, because as he sees it, the current system is working optimally.

Comment: So it's another form of, "Maybe this site is not for you"

Comment: @Adam: It would certainly be more honest to just say that. *"You seem to be unable to get through our spam filters. Maybe this site is not for you. Perhaps you would prefer experts-exchange.com?"*

Comment: *[Waves hand] "this is not the Q&A site you are looking for"*

Comment: @Benjol, but, these users can't go about their business.

Comment: "Your question is likely to be closed due to low quality.  Please read *how to ask a question* and consider re-formulating your question.  Until it is significantly improved, it is not suitable for this site."

Comment: Jeff's answer has no comments on it at this time.

Comment: Hm, yes, they have been cleared. There was a fairly involved argument there yesterday. Thanks @Rob. Summarizing from memory: the comment in question basically said "Ambiguous error messages are a UI design fail on SE's part; you should give the user feedback on _why_ things went wrong."

Answer (score 5):

In Jeff's defense, I feel compelled to point out a couple of things:

1. The secret spam filters that are now used on SO are apparently fairly effective at weeding out the marginal questions and answers.
2. The ability or willingness of these users to improve to the degree required to become good netizens at StackOverflow is *vanishingly small.*
3. Ergo, Jeff wants to provide as little information to these users as possible.

While I agree that the error message could and should be vastly improved (A link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question would suffice), it won't be improved because it will help these people.

Remember, these people already had to click through a form that gave them the basic principles for making a good post, and they still failed to muster enough quality to get through the spam filters.

Comment: I'm asking for it to be improved in order to rid us of these questions.

Comment: @SLaks: Agreed. IMO the error message MUST be improved. But not because it will help these users. That's an argument we can't win.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question/91078#91078