# Question being rejected because it doesn't meet quality standards, no specific reason

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

There are lots of questions on UML diagrams so why is this question being rejected? A little elaborated error message would not have let me to ask on meta or am i ignorant of rules/procedures

[image]

Comment: Why the underscore in your title?

Comment: @Bart I think that the filter blocks the word "question".

Comment: @Bart, yes "Question" is not allowed in the Title

Comment: That's my point exactly. Don't try to circumvent filters like that by making it a lousy title.

Comment: this version of your question looks much improved to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108660/how-to-present-static-class-or-function-call-in-sequence-diagram [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.): quality filter works as intended

Answer (score 9):

The error is vague intentionally, to avoid users [working around it without actually fixing the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/145982):

> I am against being explicit here.... Our check takes into account tags, title and body. We are not going to give breakdown of what was wrong, that is spoon feeding. ([source: waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987))
>
> If we provide a "formula" then it's just another way for users to bypass the question quality filters. ([source: Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91321#91321))

You provided a perfect example with this post. You used the title "Question is rejected by stackoverflow without exact error", and got the error "please do not use these words in titles: 'Question'". Rather than reword the title, you changed "Question" to "Ques_tion" to get around it. This is exactly the kind of thing people will do if the quality filter spells out the problems with the post, so instead it just says something is wrong and forces you to actually improve the post before you can submit it

Comment: Here you are right and i accept the reasoning, but this case started from the actual question shown in the image, imo, it was a complete question, i wanted exactly what i have asked, why should i add more details if i dont want that. First the question was rejected with vague response and then i tried to play around. If this question has been voted down just for duplication then answers should also be voted down for duplication because it is also there as reported by @Troyen in his comments. However, it looks i am against the majority which makes me reconsider this opinion. Thank you all

Answer (score 8):

First of all, your question's body is *exactly the same* as the title; that is not good. Second, it is too short; there is not a whole lot of information, which could potentially make the question hard to answer or unanswerable, in which case, it may end up closed. Lastly, it does not contain any punctuation; in my opinion, one should always endeavour to make one's posts clear and proper, and omitting punctuation is a bad way to go about doing that.

Comment: That is what i am talking about, the error message was not much clear what went wrong, the length, matching title and body or whatever. I also looked at FAQ and there was nothing similar to your answer about **Quality** so IMHO i have asked a right question.

Comment: @bjan It's not in the FAQ linked at the top, but it is in the [secret FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/160551) located here on Meta.

Comment: It means it was a right question but i was unable to find it on the meta with all possibilities. lost almost 4 out of 36 points on just a duplicate question, discouraging :(

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your subject text is exactly the same as the question you typed in the body.

Comment: i got these two error messages so i will try sometime later **1- body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 26** and **2- users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.**

Comment: @moguzalp They originally posted when the question was still on SO.

Comment: @moguzalp to complete Troyen reply - They originally posted when the question was still on SO and didn't have associated account here on Meta - bjan have such account by now, Raoul still didn't log in.

Comment: @moguzalp it should not happen, I have [submitted a bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121052/comment-authors-are-not-getting-migrated) about this issue. :)